# How to get DataStore's location using PowerCli

Tags: powershell, vmware, datastore, powercli

Using `Get-DataStore` cmdlet we get the name of datastore as `Datasore1`. But I need path of that datastore on ESX. Which is something like `/vmfs/volumes/<id>/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path is hidden inside ExtensionData property, so assign your datastore to a variable:

```powershell
$s = Get-Datastore Datasore1
```

and then extract the path:

```powershell
$s.ExtensionData.info.url
```

result:

```powershell
/vmfs/volumes/50cb7918-d31a7b14-f5a7-d89d676e15pl
```